# ¿Hay forma de bloquear que se pueda borrar la fecha de un mat datepicker?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-datepicker

Dentro de una tabla que muestra datos, tengo un campo de tipo fecha que usa un mat datepicker para modifcar la fecha y actualizarla en la BD, lo que quiero hacer es que solo te permita modificar la fecha al desplegar el calendario y bloquear/evitar  que se pueda eliminar la fecha del input como se ve en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HTML

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="fecha">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> FECHA  </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" *ngIf="element.fecha">
                            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [max]="today"
                                [value]="element.fecha"
                                (dateChange)="onDateChange($event.value,element)" [disabled]="!element.editar" />
                            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>
```

y en el component uso este metodo para obtener la fecha que se modifique

```
onDateChange(valor: Event, row: any) {
    this.idSelecc = row.id;
    this.fechaSelecc = valor;
  
  }
```

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples#datepicker-disabled
[disabled]="variable"

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con el ejemplo de la documentación

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-label>Input disabled</mat-label>
 <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp3" disabled>
 <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
 <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="dp3"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
 <mat-datepicker #dp3 disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Lo importante `<input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp3" disabled>`